# Side effects of asking co-worker to review your CV

Tags: united-kingdom, workplace-rhythm

I have this co-worker who is really clever and to the details, he knows how to structure a sentence to win the game.

Assuming they won't going to have any problem reviewing my CV, could it lead to anything serious, like a dismissal or something assuming all possible scenarios ?

Comment: Are you updating your CV because you are thinking of leaving the current workplace where you and your co worker work?

Answer (score 2):

If management get the idea that you're thinking about leaving, then they'll either seek to talk about it and see if you're happy (if they really want to retain you), or they'll side track you away from anything interesting, or just stary freezing you out.

Lead the "can you review my CV" conversation in the right way first to avoid the obvious question, and hopefully mitigate any blow-back.

> Hi Mike, I've not updated my CV in years, so I just took it out and dusted it off.  Can you take a read through and see if it looks ok to you?  I'm not looking for anything right now, I just wanted to keep it up to date in case I forget anything....

Then offer him a drink. Or something.

Whether you ask or not depends on whether you think that Mike will talk about this to your manager/lead or not.  Sometimes colleagues are trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason why somebody is updating their CV is because they are going to start applying for other jobs. It isn't part of an employee's duties to help other members of staff find new jobs, so I'd be somewhat careful about making sure all this happens very definitely "off the clock".

The other obvious risk in talking to *any* of your co-workers about plans to leave is that information gets to management before you want it to. That can make your life difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent person will keep quiet about your CV. Blabbing our that you had them look at your CV would be an absolute dick move. So it’s unlikely to happen for that reason alone. It would also make them a pariah if it became public knowledge. So unless you have a reason to distrust them, nothing will happen.

In the U.K. you cannot be fired without a reason. And writing your CV is not a reason. Writing your CV doesn’t actually mean you want to leave. It means you want to be prepared if you need it. Firing you for that would be both stupid and illegal. If your boss is a normal person, you’re fine. If not, you use your CV to get a better job. And then you can tell your boss how much more money you’re making now and hope it upsets them:-)

Comment: "In the U.K. you cannot be fired without a reason." **if you have two years service**.